# Using group and rules modules to automatically create group for new user

Tags: 8, rules, group

I am using the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) (not OG ...) and rules modules for this task. I created group type, `Applications Support`. Then I created a rule, `After saving a new user`.
Under the rule, I used the following configuration, but it did not create a group. [image]

My previous question was related to the [OG](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) module, this one is for the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module. So I think it is a different question.

Comment: @Jdrupal group and og are ***not*** the same modules ... so how can this be a duplicate???

Comment: this looks like D7 question, not D8, right?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Sorry, didn't catch that one. Close vote retracted :)

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens it is for D8 actually. I moved the website from D7 to D8.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention any errors, but for starters your group name should be:

`test group {{ user.uid }}`